# Android: How to call getActivity() in OnItemClickListener()?

Tags: java, android, casting, onitemclick, main-activity

I am trying to call getActivity() in the OnItemClickListener:

```
class ViewTest{ //called in a fragment
setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int p, long i) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).makeResultsbarVisible();
...
            }

        });
```

}

In the fragment, the class is instantiated as:

```
ViewTest editTest = new ViewTest(this);
```

But I get an error that I cannot fix:

```
The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}
```

How can I call getActivity inside onItemClick()? Thanks.

Comment: post your full class code if possible... are you using in Fragment?

Comment: Is this an activity or a fragment?

Comment: its in a class that is instantiated in a fragment

Comment: can you post your outer(main) class declaration and inner class declaration? I mean is your inner class is static?

Comment: you need to add more info to your question to get help...

Comment: is ViewTest class inner class of your Fragment class?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can only use `getActivity` inside a `Fragment` class or one extending it. If your `onItemClickListener` is in an `Activity` use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Great solution! What exactly gives me MainActivity.this when called from Listener inside MainActivity class, current instance of MainActivity??

Answer (score 0):

Use `Class_name.this` or define a `Context` variable. and then call your `makeResultsbarVisible()` by using `Context` variable,

Like,

```
Context c = this;

c.makeResultsbarVisible();
```